# How do add_action and WP_Query

Tags: plugins, functions, oop

I am new to WP, semi-new to PHP and new to OOP.

1) How can the WP function `add_action` receive another function as its argument? I know this by itself is not possible. I deliberately broke some code and found that there is actually a native php function `call_user_fun_array`,

but how did they make it so that their own function can have a function as its argument?

2) I am doing some plugin tutorial and working with WP_Query, and I just passed an argument directly to WP_Query, as if it was a method and not a class.

```
I did the following: 

$loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3
        )
);
```

I would understand if I first instantiated the class and THEN used its method, something like:

```
$loop = new WP_Query();
    $loop->someMethod(
            array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'category__in' => $cats,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'post__not_in' => array($id)
        )
);
```

but how is this possible, 
that instantiating a class can act as a method as well? (this is more of a general OOP question I guess).

Answer (score 0):

1. [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)/[add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) recive few arguments. Second one is [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).
2. It's done using [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method.

Comment: I understand the second answer but not the first. OK it is a callback, but it is still a function, and it seems to be the basis for this is the native php function i already mentioned, but I do not understand how it is done.

Comment: You don't understand what is callable data type?

Comment: If you need help understanding basic PHP datatypes and processes, perhaps this is not the best place to learn them. Consider a PHP Tutorial or the generic programming stackexchange instead.

Comment: As I said in my post, I said I didn't understand how can a custom function take another function as its argument.

Comment: `call_user_func_array` isn't a custom function.